# Split Action Bar Layout

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have implemented a split actionbar as per android documentation, by adding the following line inside the `Application` tag of my AndroidManifest.xml: `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"`. This has worked, the buttons that appear on the bottom action bar appear in a different fashion to various examples I have seen across the internet and I do not know why.

I have seen many examples on the internet appear like this:

[image]

However, the buttons on my bottom action bar appears like this:

[image]

How can I space them out so they have the same layout as the first example?

Answer (score 0):

If it renders like this, it's because your screen is larger than the examples you've seen. On your device, I guess the buttons would be too large if they filled all the space.

If you try with 5 buttons, they may suddenly fill all the space available. It really depends on the screen width.

Anyway, developers have almost no control over the layout of the split action bar. That's why several popular apps don't use the split action bar at all but use a custom layout instead (since this bar isn't really hard to reproduce).